# Difference between GND and - on power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I'm trying to power a Emlid RTK gps through its DFS connector.  There is a GND pin and a 5V pin.  I'm going to connect the 5V to '+' on my power supply but what do I connect the GND to?  GND or '-' on my power supply?  My power supply has the following 3 knobs:

```
- 
GND 
+
```

[image]

Comment: And what else is connected to this thing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the GND and "-" pins on your power supply are internally shorted, check it out with a multimeter.

Comment: @RonBeyer Doubtful. Usually the DC output is isolated, and the GND pin is provided for when earth reference is required. Connecting the two grounds willy nilly could result in nothing happening, or magic smoke escaping.

Comment: @MattYoung Magic smoke followed by my boss's wrath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should connect the GND pin of your GPS module to the '-' pin of your power supply. The '+' and the '-' pins on the power supply are designed to be the outputs of the supply. The GND pin on the supply is completely isolated from '+' and '-', and is connected to Earth, literally. It exists as a safety precaution, in case the electronics inside the power supply's casing somehow comes in contact with the casing itself, it can be shorted to the Earth, and not shock the person using it.

Explained here to: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/bench-power-supply-confusion/

Comment: @KingDuken, I'm not sure you read his answer correctly. No where does he say the "-" terminal on the power supply is the same thing as the GND terminal.

Comment: @KingDuken This answer doesn't say anything about "-" and GND being the same thing....

Comment: Unfortunatly i had a poopoo power supply, the current stayd at 0 for some reason after i connected so it didnt work anyways...